# How can I fix a zshrc:export:1: not valid in this context error when I'm installing homebrew?

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew

I am getting this error when I start up Terminal on my Mac: `.zshrc:export:1: not valid in this context`

I got this error when installing Homebrew. Can anyone help with this?

I am a beginner for this; please answer letting me know step by step how to do this will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have something wrong with line 1 of your `.zshrc` file.

1. Use a text editor like `nano` to open `~/.zshrc`

   ```
   /usr/bin/nano ~/.zshrc
   ```
2. Delete the line with ctrl-K if you don't need it.
3. Save with ctrl-X.
4. Restart Terminal.